# Frame appearing around my close icon when clicked

Tags: jquery

I have a div with an "x" image background that  I can click to close the parent element:

[image]

The code around it is:

```
function remove_cell(el) {
   $(el).closest("div.cell").remove();
}

<div class="handle">
    <div class="grip"></div>
    <div class="closeX" onclick="remove_cell(this)"> </div>
</div>
```

But when I click the "x" div I get that ugly frame around it with handles.  The remove works when the mouse button is released, but does anyone know what is putting up this frame on the mousedown and how I can get rid of it?

Thanks

Comment: What other scripts have you got loading on the page?

Comment: A demo page and the browser that you experience the issue in would be nice.

Comment: Sounds like something `outline: none` in your CSS might fix, but can't tell without the whole codez

Answer (score 0):

In your code, stop event propagation or return false to stop the click from clicking on elements below the popup window

```
function remove_cell(el) {
   $(el).closest("div.cell").remove();
   return false;
}
```

Edit: actually, since you're using inline code (not the best idea), it'll need to be inline:

```
<div class="closeX" onclick="remove_cell(this); return false"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that the larger div that this was inside of (the orange box above) had contenteditable=true.  Apparently in that case browsers (I was using FF) throw up this selection frame if you click an image element, even if the image is a background for a div you click (my div.closeX).  I got rid of it by giving the sub div (div.handle) the attribute contenteditable=false, which still left the content in the orange div editable, as it needs to be.

Works:

```
<div class="cell " contenteditable="true">
   <div class="handle" contenteditable="false">
    <div class="closeX" onclick="remove_cell(this)"> </div>
   </div>
</div>
```